# Creating a simple chat Interface using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, chat

Am currently creating a simple chat application that looks like a usual messaging service. the problem am facing is that Ive failed to add more QLabels on a QVBoxLayout by just pressing the send button. All it does is send the message to the layout as expected but when i send another message, instead of appending, it replaces the first message.
The following code is run when the send button is clicked.

```
self.message = QtGui.QLabel()
# self.messageField is the QTextEdit where the user writes the message
text = self.messageField.toPlainText()
self.message.setText(text)
self.messageField.clear()
# self.messageLayout is our QVBoxLayout
self.messageLayout.addWidget(self.message)
self.messageLayout.setAlignment(self.message, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
# self.widget is on top od the QScrollArea and it holds the QVBoxLayout
self.widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.widget.setLayout(self.messageLayout)
```

I don't know where the problem lays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.message = QtGui.QLabel()` replaces the first QLabel reference stored as an instance attribute.

Try to implement a list instead, to store all messages from the beginning.

You need to add this before, in the `__init__` method :

```
self.messages = []
```

And in the method triggered by the button :

```
message = QtGui.QLabel()

text = self.messageField.toPlainText()
message.setText(text)
self.messageField.clear()
self.messageLayout.addWidget(message)
self.widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.widget.setLayout(self.messageLayout)
# and to keep a direct reference :
self.messages.append(message)
```

EDIT :

You may need to define alignment only once at beginning, just after you define your layout, that might fix the *centered message* issue :

```
self.messageLayout = QVBoxLayout() # (i assume...)
self.messageLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

and i think you should do the same for these 2 lines, no need to repeat this each time you append a message to the list  :

```
self.widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
self.widget.setLayout(self.messageLayout)`
```

Comment: Am now having two problem.

Comment: please tell me, i suggested this without knowing the real context

Comment: The first problem is that the second QLabel is appended to the center of the Layout instead of being just below the first one. The second problem is that when I press for more QLabels, they pile up in the available space instead of scrolling.

Comment: i added some comments in EDIT, but for the scrolling part, i need more code to tell what happens, maybe this could be another question if you manage to reproduce a minimal example ?

Comment: The first problem has been solved. I didn't use self.widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.At.RightToLeft) because the received messages will be alignmened LeftToRight. The application is still not acrolling